# MySQL - insert from one table into another Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert data into a table, and use id from another table (basically use all records in that table), but I am getting this error:

```
Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

What am I doing wrong? This is the query:

```
INSERT INTO job_job_type (jobs_id, job_types_id)
VALUES
((SELECT id from jobs), 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to insert all the ids of the table jobs then use `SELECT` instead of `VALUES`:

```
INSERT INTO job_job_type (jobs_id, job_types_id)
SELECT id, 1
FROM jobs
```